# How to return multiple variables in javascript callback function?

Tags: javascript

If I have the following:

```
function hello(name, callback) {
var hello1 = "Hello There " + name;
callback(hello1);
}

hello("John", function(hello1) {
    alert(hello1);
});
```

I can get "Hello There John" in an alert box. How do I make it such that I can have a hello2 variable so that there are two variables in the callback? I essentially want to do something like:

```
function hello(name, callback) {
var hello1 = "Hello There " + name;
var hello2 = "Greetings " + name;
callback(hello1, hello2);
}

hello("John", function(hello1, hello2) {
    alert(hello1 + " " + hello2);
});
```

Comment: ummm, doesn't your example work as you want? The 2nd example.

Comment: Your title suggests you are interested in returning variables from the callback, while the question content suggests that you are interested in how to submit multiple variables as arguments. Which are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I assume the first example should have had `alert(hello1);` rather than `alert("hello1");`?

Comment: Your second example works correctly. Did you need to implement something else? I am not very clear about what you need.

Comment: I was looking for a better way to capture multiple variables in the callback besides what I had above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you got only strings values, the best will be create a array:

```
var someArray = new Array();
```

then in the function you can put the values in the array:

```
someArray[someArray.length]= "HELLO USER WITH NAME: " + name;
someArray[someArray.length]= "HELLO USER WITH NAME: " + name2;
```

and after that return the array:

```
callback(someArray); // or maybe will be better?: return someArray;
```

and in the callback function you can get the values with:

```
function callback(var retArray){
for(int i=0,i<retArray.length,i++){
console.log(retArray[i]); }
```

or you can put make your own object (function) with some strings inside..and then return this function..But if you have only string values, better will be the Array.